# ThreeJS mobile device-orientation: Chrome gets laggy, opening Firefox fixes it

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox, three.js, device-orientation

I have a mobile ThreeJS scene based on device orientation that goes quite good on Android devices (55 fps). After some time performance starts to drop badly, but this is not reflected in the FPS, only in the smoothness of the device orientation detection. And only here, because if I leave the phone on a desk (so device orientation doesn´t play any role) the rest of the code works fine and smooth as expected.

I noticed that closing the browser or even restarting the device doesn´t fix the lack of smoothness. In a moment of dispair, I tried the same script on Firefox mobile, and it was smooth. Going back to Chrome, the problem seemed to be fixed (!).

So every time Chrome gets this lag, I open Firefox to solve it, the weirdest thing. What is happening here? How can I prevent it? Also how can be possible that the fps continue being so high but the device orientation goes so laggy?

If I remember well, this started to happen after using layers on my code (combined with the StereoEffect I was already using). Does this have any sense for anybody? I´m sooo stuck on this.. Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13604#issuecomment-373547433

Comment: So it wasn´t my fault! Thank you so much for the link ;)